# Верстка циклов wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

Верстаю тему bootstrap на wordpress. Подскажите? как сверстать вывод статей, так чтобы блоки не съезжали.

На данный момент сделал так:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- the loop -->
        <?php
        // запрос
        $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'category_name'=>'projects', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));

        if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-md-4 item">
                <img src="<?php the_field('main_post_img'); ?>"/>
                <div class="details">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        else : ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Извините, нет записей, соответствуюших Вашему запросу.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы было 3 ряда по 3 поста, как выводить каждый новый ряд row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяйте в цикле, что номер выводимого поста делится на 3 нацело. Если да - начинайте новый ряд.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php
    // запрос
    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'category_name'=>'projects', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));

    $post_num = 0;
    if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) :
        $wpb_all_query->the_post();
        if (($post_num % 3) == 0)
            echo '<div class="row">';

        ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 item">
            <img src="<?php the_field('main_post_img'); ?>"/>
            <div class="details">
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Подробнее</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php

        if (($post_num % 3) == 2)
            echo '</div>';
        $post_num++;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Извините, нет записей, соответствуюших Вашему запросу.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо,работает правда немного не так.post_num = 1, так вроде бы лучше, но все равно первый col идет внутри row, остальные нет. Но в принципе пользователю норм

Comment: Ошибся. Закрывать ряд надо по сравнению == 2. Поправил ответ.